# Java logging in client application

Tags: java, logging, desktop-application

I've made a small desktop application in java for OS X. I've packaged in into a .app using JarBundler. Everything runs fine on my computer.

When I send the .app to someone else (also running a mac), the app opens and closes immediately. Is there a log file of some kind I can get from their computer (which I have full access to). Is there a way to get System.out.println statements or similar to show up in that file?

Comment: You could use log4j and specify the log file as a startup param

Answer (score 0):

execute the application from the console, from there any errors will be printed to the standard error stream.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using `System.out.println()` statements on the application. The method is synchronized and results in poor performance. Not to mention you may not be able to retrieve the statements based on who captures the console.

Use a logging solution like [sl4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and back it up with a logger like [log4j](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerAdapter.html) with a [file appender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/FileAppender). The file appender writes to a file and you can get your debug statements / stack traces from there.